# MS Graph API - Get Drive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using the `GET /users/{idOrUserPrincipalName}/drive` to get a users One Drive details.
When I try it in the Graph Explorer logged in as the admin with all the permissions consented, it works for the admin itself but for other users it says,

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "Item not found",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-01-17T21:17:04",
            "request-id": "eae1ecd1-86b4-409a-bd92-7381cff0baa2",
            "client-request-id": "3c597235-83e3-b1de-ff93-c87355eef1d1"
        }
    }
}
```

The user does have One Drive. What could be the reason?

Comment: Try to use `GET /me/drive` to get the One Drive details for the logged in user.

Comment: I would suggest what Carl said above. If you still repro the issue, share the requestid, timestamp (like what you shared above)

Comment: @Dev GET /me/drive works for sure. But I want the person logged-in (normally an admin with all the permissions) to be able to access the drive of other users. The purpose of this is ofcourse to integrate into an App where the App can display the contents of the Drive etc.,

Comment: Get the tokens of working and non-working user in https://jwt.ms, which will tell you the differences (permissions, roles assigned etc). Do the necessary changes for the affected users and try, now it will work for them. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: @Dev According to the Graph API documentation, the user trying to access another users Drive needs Files.Read, Files.ReadWrite, Files.Read.All, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All permissions. The user I am trying with has all these permissions but still it is saying, "Access denied". What's still missing?

Comment: Thats a good one. As i updated earlier, have you tried comparing both the tokens? Do you see the differences? It will tell whats wrong.

Comment: @Dev Both have the same permissions. So why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `GET /me/drive` to get the One Drive details for the logged in user.